# passing an id from view to javascript in knockout binding attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i have this link that i have a data-bind to it with attributes like the userId and typeId. How can i pass in those same id's into my javascript on ('click')... function?

```
<div class="removeUser">
    <a id="userRemoveSubmit" class="icon-minus" href="#" data-bind="attr: { 'data-user-id': ID(), 'data-type-id': TypeId()}"></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeUser', function (event) {

    $.views.Project.RemoveUser($(this).attr('data-user-id'), $(this).attr('data-type-id'));
});
```

when i try to run this i get both the userId and typeId to be undefined. How can i properly pass in the id's from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hooking up a click event handler, you could use the "click" binding in knockout.  The function called by the click binding will receive the current model value as the first paramter.  So you could do:

```
<a class="icon-minus" href="#" data-bind="click: removeUser"></a>
```

And the removeUser function in your view model could do this:

```
function removeUser(item) {
    alert(item.ID());
    alert(item.TypeId());
}
```

See the [knockout documentation on click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) (notably, "Note 1").